# Python - How to get accurate key press duration

Tags: python-3.x, time, keyboard

Whilst an .exe is running, I want to monitor if keys 'w' 's' 'a' 'd' and 'space' are being long pressed (over 1 second) or not.

The code below does not work accurately when two keys are pressed at the same time for example 'w' pressed 1st and down 3.3sec and 'd' pressed 2nd 1.5sec 'a' pressed 3rd 0.3sec whilst 'w' is still down.

I was hoping for:

- You pressed a for 0.3 seconds (pressed third)
- You pressed d for 1.5 seconds (pressed second)
- You pressed w for 3.3 seconds (pressed first)

```
import time
import keyboard

while True:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    a = keyboard.read_event()
    if a.name == "esc":
        break
    elif a.event_type == "down":
        b = keyboard.read_event()
        if a.name == "w" or a.name == "s" or a.name == "a" or a.name == "d" or a.name == "space":
            while not b.event_type == "up" and b.name == a.name:
                b = keyboard.read_event()
            end = time.perf_counter()
            print('You pressed', a.name, 'for', end-start, 'seconds.')
```

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of `pynput` and `keyboard`, this is possible.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import keyboard
import time

def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.space:
        key = 'space'
    else:
        key = key.char

    start = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        if not keyboard.is_pressed(key):
            break

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"You pressed {key.char} for {end-start} seconds.")

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

When I run this code however, I find that while it works well, the program becomes pretty laggy. I also will note that `end-start` returns a `float` type, and when I tried `int(end-start)`, the values were not very accurate since `int()` rounds down.

This code also works, however I prefer the code above, the difference is that this uses only `keyboard`.

```
import keyboard
import time

def w_pressed():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        if not keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
            break

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"You pressed w for {end-start} seconds!")

def a_pressed():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        if not keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            break

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"You pressed a for {end-start} seconds!")

def s_pressed():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        if not keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
            break

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"You pressed s for {end-start} seconds!")

def d_pressed():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        if not keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
            break

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"You pressed d for {end-start} seconds!")

keyboard.add_hotkey('w', w_pressed)
keyboard.add_hotkey('a', a_pressed)
keyboard.add_hotkey('s', s_pressed)
keyboard.add_hotkey('d', d_pressed)
```

Either way, both of these codes cause a significant amount of lag, that should be noted. I did see some code in the [documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io) for `pynput`, that allows you to specially detect if a key has been pressed longer than one second. Either way, don't rely too much on this code.